# Can healpy compute bispectrum?

Tags: python, healpy

How can I compute bispectrum using `healpy`, like I can compute angular power spectrum using anafast

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @user10971344 not yet, still trying.

Comment: any progress? i'm also curious